# How to refresh a binding of the itemssource of a combobox programmatically?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, combobox

I found some items regarding this questions on SO, but they do not satisfy me. They talk about INotifyProperyChanged, but that does not help in my case.

I have a `Combobox`.
For the `ItemsSource`, I use a `MultiBinding` and a `Converter` to create an `ICollectionView`. The `ICollectionView` gets bound to the `ItemsSource`.

On the `GotFocus`-event, this binding needs to be refreshed, so the converter gets fired again.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, a collegue helped me out.

This is the solution:

```
private void theComboBox_OnGotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox theComboBox = sender as ComboBox;

    if (theComboBox != null)
    {
        MultiBindingExpression binding = BindingOperations.GetMultiBindingExpression(theComboBox, ComboBox.ItemsSourceProperty);
        if (binding != null)
        {
            binding.UpdateTarget();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: every-time i am getting the binding as null only...
i had already given the itemsource...

Comment: I had mine set via ItemsSource, and simply setting it to null and back to the original collection did a refresh with no obvious negative side-effects.

Comment: You may try using [`BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingoperations.getbindingexpression.aspx) if you're getting null for the binding.

Answer (score 0):

If you can access your ICollectionView in your code behind, you might want to try the [Refresh](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.icollectionview.refresh.aspx) method...

Hope this helps..

Comment: That does not help.
That refreshes the ICollectionView, but the ICollectionView needs to be recreated by the Converter. So the converter needs to be refired.